# Error arising in my code. I am using React, NPM and styled components. What are the steps I need to take?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, styled-components

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Product from "./Product";
import Title from "./Title";
import { ProductConsumer } from "../context";

export default class Productlist extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="py-5">
          <div className="container">
            <Title name="our" title="products" />

            <div className="row">
              <ProductConsumer>
                {value => {
                  return value.products.map(product => {
                    return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;
                  });
                }}
              </ProductConsumer>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Error displayed on Firefox IMAGE]

Okay, I am getting this error and I am not quite sure what it is since I am so new to working with React.JS. could someone assist me in figuring out what may be happening.

```
export default class Product extends Component {
  render() {
    const { id, title, img, price, inCart } = this.props.product;
    return (
      <ProductWrapper className="col-9 mx-auto col-md-6 col-lg-3 my-3">
        <div className="card">
          <div
            className="img-container p-5"
            onClick={console.log("you clicked me on the image container")}
          >
            <Link to="/details">
              <img src={img} alt="product" className="card-img-top" />
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ProductWrapper>
    );
  }
}

const ProductWrapper = styled.div
```

Above is the Product code as asked! Thank you!

Comment: `return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;` is where the issue is I think - are you sure of passing the complete object inside product? should it be `return <Product key={product.id} product={product.displayName} />;` or something?

Comment: Please try to include all relevant code, in this case it does indeed appear that `Product` is possibly a candidate. Can you update your question to include `Product`'s component code?

Comment: @DrewReese here is my product component code. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Hmm, I'm 99% sure the correct syntax for styled components is `const ProductWrapper = styled.div\`\`;`

Comment: OH MY GOD THAT WAS IT! i feel dumb. Thank you so much @DrewReese!